# Can I add a command to the console using a Chrome extension in the inspect?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I am currently developing a Chrome extension that allows users to insert a custom command into the console when they inspect a web page. But my extension is not working as expected.

Here's what I have tried so far:

- I created the necessary files, including manifest.json, background.js, popup.html, and popup.js.
- I added the required permissions and background service worker in the manifest.json file, following the new Manifest version 3 guidelines.
- I used `chrome.scripting.executeScript` to inject the command into the console within my background.js file.
- When I click the extension icon, the popup appears, but nothing happens when I click the "Insert Command" button.

1. **manifest.json**:

```json
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "Console Command Inserter",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "Inserts a command into the console.",
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "permissions": ["scripting"],
  "host_permissions": ["<all_urls>"],
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  }
}
```

2. **background.js**:

```js
// background.js

// Function to inject code into the current tab's console
function injectCode(tab) {
  chrome.scripting.executeScript({
    target: { tabId: tab.id },
    func: () => {
      console.log('Hello, this is inserted code!');
    },
  });
}

// Listen for the extension icon click event and inject the code into the active tab's console
chrome.action.onClicked.addListener(function (tab) {
  injectCode(tab);
});
```

3. **popup.html**:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Console Command Inserter</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Console Command Inserter</h1>
  <button id="insertButton">Insert Command</button>

  <script src="popup.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

4. **popup.js**:

```js
// popup.js

// Function to send a message to the background script to inject code into the console
function insertCode() {
  chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ action: "injectCode" });
}

// Add a click event listener to the button
document.getElementById("insertButton").addEventListener("click", insertCode);
```

I tried to troubleshoot the issue myself, but I couldn't figure out what went wrong. I suspect that I might be missing something or not using the correct method to inject the command into the console.

If you have any insights or suggestions to help troubleshoot the issue, please post your answers below. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: 1) Remove `background` from manifest.json and delete background.js. 2) Move the contents of injectCode inside insertCode instead of sendMessage line. 3) Remove `host_permissions` and add "activeTab" to "permissions".

Comment: @wOxxOm, i applied the changes but its still not working.

Comment: Debug it. Note that the popup is a separate window so it has its own separate devtools: right-click inside the popup and select "inspect" in the menu. Also don't forget to reload the extension in chrome://extensions page.